# Kivymd change Icon in OneLineIconListItem without removing the whole widget

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

```
OneLineIconListItem:
    id: status
    text:'Status:       '+root.status
    pos_hint_y: 0.5
    IconLeftWidget:
        id: left_icon
        icon:"alert"
        theme_text_color:'Custom'
        text_color: 255 / 256, 165 / 256, 0, 1
```

I want to change the Icon and its colour without removing the whole widget, but i cant access the icon attribute. I tried
... .ids.status.ids._left_container.ids but there is no icon attribute present.